# How to annotate voltage with plus and minus signs beside a line?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-circuit-lib

I am trying to add a voltage annotation on the right side of a current source in the circuit below. (Sorry for my bad handwriting and drawing!)

[image: actual and goal circuits]

First I drew the "Actual" circuit with the code:

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[%
            circuit ee IEC,
            x=2cm, y=4cm,
            semithick,
            every info/.style={font=\large},
            huge circuit symbols]
        \draw (0, 0) to [current source={direction info={info={$\dot{I}_s$}}}] (0, 1);
        \draw (1, 1) to [capacitor={info={$C$}}] (1, 0);
        \draw (2, 1) to [%
            inductor={near start, info={$L$}},
            resistor={near end, info={$R$}}] (2, 0);
        \draw (0, 1) -- (2, 1) (2, 0) -- (0, 0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But I am not very familiar with the circuit library and not sure how to easily add plus and minus signs at each corner of the line respectively, like the "Goal" one in the image. I think it is possible to specify the coordinates explicitly and draw some nodes labelled with these signs, but it may be annoying when some parts of the circuit change. I wonder whether there is any easy way to accomplish the goal.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help) Please always show a complete minimal working example from `\documentclass` down to `\end{document}` instead of a code snippet only. This would help us to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to specify coordinates and nodes as they actually are already in place. You can add a node option to the path of your drawing and adjust the position of the label using the placement keys.

From your goal this is what you want to achieve:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[%
        circuit ee IEC,
        x=2cm, y=4cm,
        semithick,
        every info/.style={font=\large},
        huge circuit symbols]
        \draw (0, 0) to [current source={direction info={info={$\dot{I}_s$}}}] node[right,xshift=1em]{$\dot{V}_s$} (0, 1);
        \draw (1, 1) to [capacitor={info={$C$}}] (1, 0);
        \draw (2, 1) to [%
        inductor={near start, info={$L$}},
        resistor={near end, info={$R$}}] (2, 0);
        \draw (0, 1) node[below right]{$+$} --  (2, 1) (2, 0) -- node[above, xshift=-5em]{$-$} (0, 0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, I just added some nodes and placement options to your code. The result:

[image: circuit]

You can change the position of the charges `+` and `-` according to your needs.

Comment: Thank you a lot! Everything works well. I also move the declaration of "+" and "-" nodes to line 11 (`\draw (0, 0) ...`) so that there is no need to set `xshift` for the "-" node.